# How do you create a unit-testing stub for an interface containing a read-only member?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, properties, readonly

I am writing some unit tests for an extension method I have written on `IPrincipal`.  To assist, I have created a couple of helper classes (some code for not-implemented members of the interfaces has been omitted for brevity):

```
public class IPrincipalStub : IPrincipal
{
    private IIdentity identityStub = new IIdentityStub();

    public IIdentity Identity
    {
        get { return identityStub; }
        set { identityStub = value; }
    }
}

public class IIdentityStub : IIdentity
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // BZZZT!!!
}
```

However, the `Name` property in the `IIdentity` interface is read-only (the `IIDentity` interface specifies a getter but not a setter for the Name property).

How can I set the Name property in my stub object for testing purposes if the interface has defined it as a read-only property?

Comment: Constructor? i.e `IIdentityStub` will have a parameterized constructor that takes Name as parameter.

Comment: Did your "BZZZT" refer to a compile error?  I was able to compile your sample just fine (w/semi-colons on the Identity property, that is).

Comment: @micahtan: Yes, but when you try to write a test against it, and set the value of `Name` in the test, the compiler will complain that `Name` is read-only, because the `Name` property in `IIDentity` does not have a setter defined.

Comment: I was thinking of setting IPrincipalStub.Identity to an instance of IIdentityStub that you construct (thus taking advantage of the setter) instead of using the constructor-created field.  I guess it depends on what you want your setup code to look like in your unit tests.

Comment: @Micahtan: I wound up putting a constructor in `IPrincipalStub` that accepted the `Name` as a string, and passed it along to the `IIDentityStub` constructor that also accepted the name as a string.  Eventually, I will be doing everything in Moq, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the auto-properties feature of C# but instead you should go the manual route and create a backing field for the property.  Once you have a backing field you can set its value in the constructor (or make it a public field and set it after you have the object, but this is a little uglier).

```
public class IIdentityStub : IIdentity{
    private string _name;

    public IIdentityStub(string name){
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
}
```

Comment: And if the value isn't settable via the constructor, you have a problem with your design.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: No problem sir.

Comment: Note that "public string Name { get; private set; }" and then setting in the constructor is perfectly legal.

Comment: @TrueWill: Yes, but that would not match the signature of the `IIdentity` interface `Name` property.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with juharr - use a mocking/isolation framework. I'd recommend [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

The following will print "Robert":

```
using System;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Moq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var mockIdentity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
            var mockPrincipal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();

            mockIdentity.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns("Robert");
            mockPrincipal.SetupGet(x => x.Identity).Returns(mockIdentity.Object);

            IPrincipal myStub = mockPrincipal.Object;

            Console.WriteLine(myStub.Identity.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** But if you want to do it by hand...

```
using System;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IIdentity identity =
                new IdentityStub
                    {
                        Name = "Robert",
                        AuthenticationType = "Kerberos",
                        IsAuthenticated = true
                    };

            IPrincipal principal = new PrincipalStub(identity);

            Console.WriteLine(principal.Identity.Name);  // Robert
            Console.WriteLine(principal.IsInRole(PrincipalStub.ValidRole));  // True
            Console.WriteLine(principal.IsInRole("OtherRole"));  // False
        }
    }

    public class PrincipalStub : IPrincipal
    {
        public const string ValidRole = "TestRole";

        public PrincipalStub(IIdentity identity)
        {
            Identity = identity;
        }

        public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

        public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            return role == ValidRole;
        }
    }

    public class IdentityStub : IIdentity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }
        public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(The above is **not** a unit test, just an example of hand-rolled stubs using a bit of dependency injection.)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a Mock library like [NMock](http://www.nmock.org/)

Comment: True, but I figured I'd better learn how to write my own stubs first.