# setup function to return result of same function that is being setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, autofac

I am setting up a function in a unit test and want to return result of same function that is being setup.

Interface looks like this.

```
 public interface ICommonServices
{
    int[] GetIntArray();
    int AddOne(int a);
}
```

Interface is implemented like this.

```
  public int AddOne(int a)
    {
        return a + 1;
    }
    public int[] GetIntArray()
    {
        int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        return x;
    }
```

Service Under Test (ObservationService) has a function that needs to be  tested.

```
public string SomeCalculation()
    {
        var intArray = _commonServices.GetIntArray();
        List<int> result = intArray.Select(x => _commonServices.AddOne(x)).ToList();
        //Do Something With result.
        return "Done";
    }
```

where _commonServices is injecting using a DI.

and my Unit Test Looks like this

```
   [Test]
    public void Some_Test()
    {
        int[] a = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
        {
            // Arrange          
            mock.Mock<ICommonServices>().Setup(x => x.GetIntArray()).Returns(a);
            mock.Mock<ICommonServices>().Setup(x => x.AddOne(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(/* what to do here AddOne(x)   */);
            var sut = mock.Create<ObservationService>();
            // Act
            var res = sut.SomeCalculation();
            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual("Done", res);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to Setup "AddOne" function to return the result of its own.

Comment: Why to mock something which does only `a + 1`? It is not necessary to mock it at all.

Comment: this is just an example. in real code lot more is happening.

Comment: So then you will probably have to simplify the test so it tests some more specific case and to return exactly the value of the function AddOne which corresponds with this specific test case?

Comment: What are the conditions for the test? Could you use this naming pattern? [UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155436/unit-test-naming-best-practices).

Comment: your sut should not be mocked. you mock the dependencies of the sut

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you correctly.

Here is what you could do:

```
mock.Mock<ICommonServices>().Setup(x => x.AddOne(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns( (int a) =>
                                                                        {
                                                                            return a + 1;
                                                                        });
```

**How to reuse the `AddOne()` method:**

1. Declare your `AddOne()` as `static`

```
public class CommonServices : ICommonServices
{
    public static int AddOne(int a)
    {
        return a + 1;
    }
}
```

2. Now you can use your `static` method in your mockup

```
mock.Mock<ICommonServices>().Setup(x => x.AddOne(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns( (int a) =>
                                                                            {
                                                                                return CommonServices.AddOne(a);
                                                                            });
```

Comment: but than i have to write a+ 1 function again. cant i use the same function?

Comment: Sure you can, but then you need to declare you `AddOne` method as static. In this case please refer to this post: [Mock a Method with Moq and make moq.Object available there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147215/mock-a-method-with-moq-and-make-moq-object-available-there)

Comment: but than i am changing my code to suit my test which is against the unit testing concepts. isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

solution was to moq the CommonService

```
   var cs = mock.Create<CommonServices>();
```

and use it in return

```
mock.Mock<ICommonServices>().Setup(x => x.AddOne(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns( (int a) =>
                                                                        {
                                                                            return cs.AddOne(a);
                                                                        });
```